# Boost: Generic Graph. How to create a generic graph

Tags: c++, templates, generics, boost, graph

Currently i try to work with the boostGraph library.

What is the best solution to generate a generic class for direct and undirect Graphs.

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,  boost::no_property, EdgeWeightProperty>DirectedGraph;
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, boost::no_property, EdgeWeightProperty>UndirectedGraph;

    template<class T>
class GraphNet {

    // Retrieve the weight of an edge
    typedef typename boost::property_map<T,
    boost::edge_weight_t>::type EdgeWeightMap;
    typedef typename boost::property_map<T,
    boost::vertex_index_t>::type IndexMap;
    ...

public:

std::pair<edge_iterator, edge_iterator>edgePair;
std::pair<vertex_iter, vertex_iter>vertexPair;
...
};
```

How can i define an object with unknown type in my Main? Now i have just the possibility to generate a DirectedGraph or UndirectedGraph. Also i want a list or vector with different graphTypes.

```
  GraphNet<DirectedGraph>  graphNet;
 std::vector<GraphNet<DirectedGraph>> vecGraphs;
```

What is the right statement to generate a object or vector with unknown type? Any suggestions to solve this?
Thank you

Comment: What do you really want to do? Genericity is already offered by boost graph's templates

Comment: The user should be able to create a directed or undirected graph. Depending on the selection, the graph should be generated in a global variable. 

Now im just able to define a global variable for directed Graph and one Variable for undirected Graph. 

By the way is there a possibility to change the property of the graph from  directionalS to undirectionalS and vice versa after graph creation?

Comment: The said property is embedded in a template parameter so no, it's not possible to switch it at runtime (and it's expected and sane that way). You still seem to have no clear idea of what you want to _really_ achieve. What is the actual problem at hand